# Update Vim in RHEL to version 7.4.2009

Tags: rhel, vim, upgrade

I am trying to write a Go server on a RHEL 7 system, but the Vim plugin, [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go), requires version 7.4.2009, where the system only has 7.4.1099. I have tried

```
yum install vim
```

and it already has the latest version.

```
Package 2:vim-enhanced-7.4.160-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Question is, how can I update Vim such that it will support Go syntax highlighting?

Comment: You'll need to hand compile (and maintain!) a modern version of `vim` or instead backport (and maintain!) a custom RPM for a modern version of `vim`, both of which have various complications (and maintenance problems over time).

Comment: What thrig said, plus “or wait for RedHat to release that version”

Answer (score 0):

The `vim-go` software is packaged for CentOS 7 already, does that not work for you?

You can find the RPM in the EPEL repositories: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/v/vim-go-1.8-3.el7.x86_64.rpm

This leads me to believe that the version of `vim` packaged for CentOS 7 has the needed requirements to run `vim-go`.

If that still does not work, post what errors and issues you continue to experience.